# Can I add a JSP to my IBM Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible to add a jsp file to my IBM Worklight Server If Yes then how to do it and what will be the procedure to access it ?

Any solution or knowledge will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use JSP in Worklight Server.

Comment: Okey Thanks. I just wanted to have my UI to send push notifications to my users. Like write some message and send to all my users. In console there is no option to do it which is very less user friendly from a Admin perspective.